# How to check in the page if the name exists and then increment a unique name

Tags: selenium-webdriver, java, javascript, cucumber, web-application

I have a scenario where I need to add new username everytime is run the script. For instance, if the last time I had added a name as test1, then next time when I add another name I should not add test1 since it is already added instead I should add test2.

Incrementing the text is fine I have used the below script

```
String user_id = AppXPathsConstants.user_id;
num++;
```

But my question is how to find that test1 already exists then add test 2 then after adding test2 I need to add test3 since test2 already exists.

Comment: How are you retrieving the user names ?

Comment: Add your element that displays usernames in UI

Comment: hi jon,  I would need help to increment the property - Key with a unique name and not sure how to do can you pls help

Answer (score 1):

You have several ways to go:

**If your app is pure black-box**

- Store what you already created in memory of your test. Example - parameterization that cucumber supplies. The downside is that when your tests are done and re-run they will start from scratch so you will have to reset your application database
- If you have any interface that your application exposes that can list already created users, you can use that interface. The downside is that it will be likely working slowly.
- You can attempt to create users and rely on your application that would be reporting that such user exists. Then you will be handling such response and roll the number of your user and try again and again. The downside is that it will be very slow and will rely on your app that might have defects, etc..
- You can make your user have [UUID](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/UUID.html) in their account names. Like `UUID.randomUUID().toString()`. This will ensure they are unique.

**If you own application infrastructure**

- Your tests can take the list of created users directly from the application database. Downside is that you will need to maintain some code to query the database
- Ask your devs (or try yourself) to expose some additional interface (e.g. REST) that can list created users or take the latest created one. Then you will be able to use that interface to generate new user that yet does not exist.

Comment: this testing is done in java seleniumn and hence I need to read the values from the screen. is there any other inputs kindly guide

Comment: Use `UUID.randomUUID().toString()`

Comment: what will this do? and where should I add this code...this is a user screen where any new user needs access to the application we enter the information of that user over here.that being the case there are existing usernames and I need to read the userid column in the screen and then need to add a new user everytime...

Comment: This will generate the unique String that will not ever repeat in future so that you can add that part to your user name that will also become unique.

Comment: int j=0;
      for(int count1=0; count1 <10000; j++){
       DriverUtil.waitTime(4000);
       Date d = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis());
       
       driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[contains(@name,'userIdInputInTxtWoPnlGrid')]")).sendKeys("test"+j);
       j++;

Comment: in this code where should I add UUId pls suggest this code should add new username everytime I run it but It generates the same name everytime I run it …. the name being added in send keys....iam automating in java seleniumn using cucumber framework

Comment: Can you pls give more inputs pls

Comment: I do not know. I do not understand how your code is relevant to what you're asking. You were asking about adding a user each time the test runs. Now you're showing that you add users in a loop within a test. You have to provide minimal reproducible example.

Comment: 1)First I read the values from the  user_id column in the screen and below is the code for that:List<WebElement> useridcolvalue = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@id='mainForm:allUsersTable_data']/tr/td[1]"));
 
   for(int i=0;i<useridcolvalue.size();i++)
    
    {
              
    String colval = useridcolvalue.get(i).getText();
    System.out.println("Get the userid"+colval);

Comment: 2)Next I click on the Add button and then I need help about how to add a unique user i.e. after reading the column values and navigating to the add screen how to know that the value that is going to be added everytime is not there in the screen... i.e. I am not aware of how to compare the column values and then add a unique user name this is the question...Hope iam clear now

Comment: You do not need to read existing users. If you build your user name like `String userName = "test_" + UUID.randomUUID().toString()` this will guarantee that there is no user with such name in the table yet.

Comment: So you are saying that I just need to click the add button and enter String userName = "test_" + UUID.randomUUID().toString() ; and pass this user name to the userid field kindly confirm if my understanding is right

Comment: Yes. That is right.

Comment: let me try and get back to you in few mins

Comment: Superb Alexey thank you so much its a big issue that you have helped me with is there any ways I can reach out to you going forward since iam new to automation testing and need guidenance kindly sugggest

Comment: You can send me message [here](https://www.webelement.click/en/feedback)

Comment: thank you very much will come back with some more questions

Comment: Hi Alex I have sent a message with the question and script to the link that you have provided in order to reach you.can you please guide me

Comment: HI Alex have sent a question in the link that you have provided to reach out to you can you pls guide me as iam stuck